# One or more network protocols are missing on this computer (Windows 10)

Tags: networking, windows-10

I've attempted to reset winsock, reset itp, reset IVP4 and 6. I don't know what else to try at this point. I don't want to reset/restore the computer.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I don't even know why this happened. The computer was asleep, I opened it and there was no internet.

Comment: I had this same issue the other day out of nowhere on windows 10. I tried all of the above too ended up somehow some files got currupted and I couldn't fix it I did 'sfc /scannow' via command prompt or cmd.exe and tried to repair it but ended up restoring. I would also like to know how to fix this if it ever happens again.

Comment: I just had the same thing today after an update overnight. I noticed Network was claiming to be 'Network 2' & set to Public with no connectivity. Simply disabling, then re-enabling the NIC from Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections did it for me. The mysterious 'missing network protocols' were suddenly no longer missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

1. Hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and Press <kbd>W</kbd> (for Network Connections).
2. Right-click the adapter and go to properties.
3. Click Install... > Protocol > Anything from that list. For me I installed "Reliable Multicast Protocol".
4. Click Ok until you're back at Network Connections Window
5. Right-click your adapter > Disable .. wait a few seconds >> Enable again
6. At this point it was fixed for me, but give it a minute if it didn't work immediately.

Note: if network sharing is enabled you might want to try and disable that.